# Can a group act on the empty set?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

There isn't much more to add to this question. Can we define an action between some group and the null set?

I would have thought that there being no elements to act on it trivially satisfies the requirements for something to be an action but I'm not sure.

Comment: Though it's kind of empty to have a group action on an empty set, isn't it? =)

Comment: In particular, the symmetric group $S_0$, which has order $1$, acts naturally on the empty set. There is unique bijection between the empty set and itself.

Comment: @user21820 the interest of a mathematical formalism is to avoid such philosophical considerations. In the same spirit, there were mathematicians fighting against the existence of infinite sets in the late XIX...

Comment: @YCor: Erm... I was just joking in my first comment, but I disagree with your comment, because anyone who claims they use ZFC as their foundational system necessarily has made some very weird philosophical assumptions whether or not they know it.

Comment: @user21820 the point is that once you use ZFC, you don't have to bother anymore with philosophy (at least as regards truth within set theory). And it's also the case in set theory, when you rather deal with various models of ZF.

Comment: @YCor: But that's only if you think "truth within set theory" is meaningful. To refrain from prolonging this thread with our off-topic discussion, do you want to come to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic)?

Comment: No I don't have much more to say, and maybe I already said too much here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes you can define the trivial action.

Note that the axioms for group action begins with "for all"

That is:

For all $x\in \emptyset$ we have that $e.x=x$.

For all $x\in\emptyset$ and all $g,h\in G$ we have $(gh)x=g.(h.x)$

Both statements hold trivially.